# Do simple carbohydrates affect skin quality?

Tags: dermatology, sugar

Does eating simple carbohydrates affects the skin quality ? Will it make skin dark, old, dull, dry, wrinkled, saggy, or cause fine lines or age spots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, long-term eating of a large amount of simple carbohydrates may affect skin quality.

[Nutrition and aging skin: sugar and glycation (PubMed, 2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20620757)

> The effect of sugars on **aging skin** is governed by the simple act of
>   covalently cross-linking two collagen fibers, which renders both of
>   them incapable of easy repair. Glucose and fructose link the amino
>   acids present in the collagen and elastin that support the dermis,
>   producing advanced glycation end products or "AGEs." This process is
>   accelerated in all body tissues when sugar is elevated and is further
>   stimulated by ultraviolet light in the skin.

[Diet and Dermatology (PubMed Central, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4106357/)

> **Rhytides, sagging of skin, and loss of elasticity** are all related to changes in the collagen and elastic fibers of the skin, which are
>   themselves impacted by diet. Ingestion of sugar, in particular, can
>   accelerate these signs of aging...
>
> **Foods with a high glycemic index, such as sugar,** white bread, and white rice, are rapidly absorbed, leading to higher serum glucose
>   levels and corresponding elevated levels of insulin. Insulin and IGF-1
>   have been shown to augment sebum production, stimulate adrenal
>   androgen synthesis, and increase androgen bioavailability, all of
>   which play a role in the pathogenesis of **acne.**